# laravel Where on nested with

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

i want to get the location with all his disponibilites who didn't have etat="archiver"

Disponibilite

```php
class Disponibilite extends Model
{
    public function etat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Etat');
    }
}
```

location

```php
class location extends Model
{
    public function disponibilite()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Disponibilite');
    }
}
```

etat is empty

```
class Etat extends Model
{
}
```

this is my tried

```php
$location = location::where("id", $id)
->with([
    "locataire",
    "prix",
    "acceptations",
    "distances",
    "equipements",
    "logement",
    "language",
    "photo",
    "disponibilite" => function ($query) {
        $query->with(["etat" => function ($q) {
            $q->where("type", "!=", "archiver");
        }]);
    }
])
->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it, the problem  there is some rows of disponibilites  have had a etat (NULL)
so if i've testing the type of etat (null) in the callback function nothing is will happen So i add OrWhere("etat_id",null) and I changed the with  with wherehas

```
$location = location::with(
                [
                    "locataire",
                    "prix",
                    "acceptations",
                    "distances",
                    "equipements",
                    "logement",
                    "language",
                    "photo",
                    "disponibilite" => function ($query) {

                        $query->whereHas("etat", function ($q) {

                            $q->where("type", "!=", "archiver");
                        })->Orwhere("etat_id", null);
                    }
                ]
            )
                ->find($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$location = location::with([
    "locataire",
    "prix",
    "acceptations",
    "distances",
    "equipements",
    "logement",
    "language",
    "photo",
    "disponibilite" => function ($disponibilite) {
        // only get the 'disponibilites' that has the following relationship
        $disponibilite->whereHas("etat", function ($etat) {
            $etat->where("type", "!=", "archiver");
        })
        // eager load the relationship
        ->with(["etat" => function ($etat) {
            $etat->where("type", "!=", "archiver");
        }]);
    }
])
// This is the same as using where('id', $id)->first()
->find($id);
```

Comment: I want to keep the location whatever,But the disponibilite depend on the type of etat ,Tnx